# Third Party Apps Installed In Django Location

Tags: python, django

So I've installed django-messages and django-notifications into my django projects, when i was in src with pip install django-messages etc. However i can find where the files are, ive done a search of the whole folder but nothing, I've looked in lib/site-packages but nothing. Are they even in my folder or being hosted elsewhere, its so confusing.

please help

Comment: What OS, python version, using virtenv etc.?

Comment: windows, python version 2.7 and i am using virtenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

> Where ENV is a directory to place the new virtual environment.
>
> ...
>
> Packages installed in this environment will live under
>   ENV/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/.
>
> ...
>
> Some paths within the virtualenv are slightly different on Windows:
>   scripts and executables on Windows go in ENV\Scripts\ instead of
>   ENV/bin/ and libraries go in ENV\Lib\ rather than ENV/lib/.

ENV\Lib\python2.7\site-packages\ in your case where ENV is where you created your virtual environment.

EDIT: 
or try

```
pip freeze
```

this will show all packages installed by pip. Get the names of the packages you are interested in e.g. django-notifications then run:

```
pip show django-notifications
```

This will output amongst other things Location data.

Comment: hi, thank you, but for some reason when i install a third party app with pip install it installs in in another places

Comment: If you're using a virtual environment it should get installed into Lib\python2.7\site-packages\ under the directory you created the virtual environment in is it possible these are hidden under Windows?

Comment: Can you list the files and directories in the directory you created the virtual environment in?

Comment: Thankyou figured it out